# Flask-WTForms form.validate() fails on dynamic choices

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I'm creating a survey application that displays the survey question and choices and allows the user to pick a choice through the Flask-WTForms package.  The form uses a `RadioField` and seems to fail `form.validate()` when populating the choices attribute dynamically.

When I manually enter in the choices as such:

```
class SurveyAnswerForm(FlaskForm):
    answers = RadioField('Answers',
                         coerce=str,
                         choices=[('18-25', '18-25'), ('26-35', '26-35')])
```

`form.validate()` returns **True** and there are no errors in `form.error`.

When I decide to populate the choices attribute dynamically (see below), `form.validate()` returns **False** and `form.error` returns:

> {'answers': ['Not a valid choice']}.

I've been working at this for hours and am not sure why `form.validate()` returns **False**.

**forms.py**:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import RadioField

class SurveyAnswerForm(FlaskForm):
    answers = RadioField('Answers',
                         coerce=str,
                         choices=[])
```

**app.py**:

```
@app.route('/survey/<int:survey_id>/questions', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def survey_questions(survey_id):
    survey = Survey.query.filter_by(id=survey_id).first()
    page = request.args.get('page', 1, type=int)
    questions = SurveyQuestion.query.filter_by(survey_id=survey_id)\
        .order_by(SurveyQuestion.id)\
        .paginate(page, 1, True)

    for question in questions.items:
        question_id = question.id

    choices = QuestionChoices.query\
        .join(SurveyQuestion,
              and_(QuestionChoices.question_id==question_id,
               SurveyQuestion.survey_id==survey_id)).all()

    form = SurveyAnswerForm(request.form)
    form.answers.choices = [(choice.choice, choice.choice)\
        for choice in choices]

    if request.method =='POST' and form.validate():
        print('Successful POST')

    next_url = url_for('survey_questions', survey_id=survey.id,
                       page=questions.next_num)\
        if questions.has_next else None
    prev_url = url_for('survey_questions', survey_id=survey.id,
                   page=questions.prev_num)\
        if questions.has_prev else None

    return render_template('survey_question.html',
                           survey=survey,
                           questions=questions.items,
                           choices=choices,
                           form=form,
                           next_url=next_url, prev_url=prev_url)
```

**survey_question.html**:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
  <h2>{{ survey.survey_title }}</h2>
  {% for question in questions %}
    <h3>{{ question.question }}</h3>
  {% endfor %}

  <form action="{{ next_url }}" method="POST">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ form.answers(name='answer') }}

    {% if prev_url %}
      <a href="{{ prev_url }}">Back</a>
    {% endif %}
    {% if next_url %}
      <input type="submit" value="Continue">
   {% else %}
      <a href="#">Finish</a>
    {% endif %}
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any mention of `form.validate()` in your code.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I edited the code to show where it would validate.  'Successful POST' is never printed out.

Comment: Ended up spending two hours to get flask running again (via debugging mode for crying out-loud), then followed by hitting your "survey_id" and missing survey_questions folder and content. .. and the duh moment! This was too long ago for me... logging out on this topic.GL.

Comment: https://github.com/laskeym/Flask_Survey.git

set environment variables `FLASK_APP=app.py` and `FLASK_DEBUG=1` and then run `flask run`

Comment: I seem to have found the problem.  It has something to do with submitting the form to the `{{ next_url }}` url.  I rewrote this script without pagination, only submitting to `/survey/<survey_id>/questions` and was able to validate the form.  It's when I use pagination and submit the form to `/survey/survey_id/questions?page=2` that the form seems to either lose or overwrite the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was submitting a POST request with pagination.  if the current link is `/survey/1/question?page=2` the form will submit to `/submit/1/question?page=3`.  To remedy this, I just created a separate route for submission and handled logic there.

Comment: can you show me how you done this please? I am getting really stuck doing the same thing. I have 36 pages, but each time I select a checkbox on one page and then change page it loses that state already